# AWS EC2 CentOS 7 Usardata file fails to load on initial boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, user-data

I'm trying to pass simple bash script to an AWS CentOS 7 instance. User Data looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
```

Here is a fragment of cloud init log:

```
Apr  1 19:03:01 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: /usr/bin/env: bash  yum update -y : No such file or directory
Apr  1 19:03:01 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: 2016-04-01 19:03:01,604 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [127]
Apr  1 19:03:01 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: 2016-04-01 19:03:01,616 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Apr  1 19:03:01 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: 2016-04-01 19:03:01,617 - util.py[WARNING]: Running scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

I tried a different approach as suggested in:
[Bash script passed to AWS EC2 Instance as User Data file fails to load on initial boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916167/bash-script-passed-to-aws-ec2-instance-as-user-data-file-fails-to-load-on-initia/33902510)

So I changed User Data to:

```
"UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
            "#!/bin/bash\n\n",
            "yum update -y"
        ]]}}
```

I got different kind of error:

```
Apr  1 19:28:17 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: 2016-04-01 19:28:17,450 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: '"UserData" : { "Fn::Base...'
Apr  1 19:28:20 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 01 Apr 2016 19:28:20 +0000. Up 48.56 seconds.
Apr  1 19:28:21 ip-172-20-60-102 cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 01 Apr 2016 19:28:20 +0000. Up 48.89 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path. Try `/usr/bin/yum -y update` .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11867699)

Comment: Thanks dear Todd. I edited the answer to be a real answer not a question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried as you suggested, i got the same error: